# iterate text boxes by a for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, for-loop

Say I have 10 text boxes and I want to put the same text into each of them. I don't want to write `textBoxNum. Text = "hello!"` ten times so I might write something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    textBox + i. Text = "hello!";
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work.

How can this be done with a `for` loop ?

Comment: You should name your textboxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need to load all of your textboxes into a list or array structure, and this will allow you to iterate over it.

```
TextBox[] boxes = { tb1, tb2, tb3, ... };
```

Otherwise, you could inspect the `Controls` property of your form/container for items of the `TextBox` type. If the controls could be nested in deeper containers, you might need to recursively explore them (at this point, I would seriously consider an array approach, unless you have some ghastly number of textboxes to load). But as a starting point, you might have

```
foreach (var tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    tb.Text = "whatever";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should put your textboxes into an array:

```
TextBox[] boxes;

public MyForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    boxes = { someTextBox, otherTextBox, ... };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
foreach (Control c  in this.Controls)
{
     if (c is TextBox)
     {
         ((TextBox)c).Text = "Hello";
     }
}
```

Assuming you want to set the text of all textboxes contained on the control\form, but can be modified for more specific scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You could also edit controls only matching something that you want. Here's an example.

```
foreach(Control ctrl in Controls)
  {
    if (ctrl.Name.StartsWith("TextBoxToEdit"))
    {
      ctrl.Text = "Hello!";
    }
  }
```

Also, there is no need to cast the control into TextBox as Control already has the Text property.

Comment: It may have the `Text` property, but you still want to verify `if (ctrl is TextBox) {}`. Anything can have a name that starts with "TextBoxToEdit".